# How do get contents of a p element one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I need to parse the contents of each `<p>` tag individually and then replace the text with the new text.

The code at the moment looks like:

```
str = $('p').text();
str = str.replace('yadayada','yada');
$('p').text(str);
```

This is currently getting the contents of all the `<p>` tags, concatenating them then replacing the massive block of text into each `<p>` which is close but not quite what I'd like it to do.

Is there a way to get the contents of each `<p>` block one at a time and replacing it with only it's contents? I do not know what ids or classes are being applied to them hence the need to use the generic tag.

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Use the version of `.text()` with the callback: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`text(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

> A function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.

```
$('p').text(function(_ text){
    return text.replace('yadayada','yada');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `text()` version that accepts a callback as the second argument and return the replaced content from the callback

```js
$('p').text(function(i, str) {
  return str.replace('yadayada', 'yada');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>yadayada-1</p>
<p>yadayada-2</p>
<p>yadayada-3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each` method on the colletion:

```
$('p').each(function (pEl) {
    var text = pEl.textContent;
});
```